# How an SNMP master Python script can load an SNMP get respose into python data structure?

Tags: snmp, mib, pysnmp

Using pysnmp or any other library, is it possible to take the response from a SNMP get/getbulk request and automatically populate a Python data structure (class, etc) based on the MIB?

Cheers,
Donal

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?
In other words, what did you try?

Comment: Response message from SNMP Agent is a binary, BER encoded string. When you pass it to pysnmp (for instance), it can produce an initialized data structure representing SNMP Response message. You could then pass the var-bindings part of it to pysnmp's SMI subsystem which, in some cases, could return a better human-oriented representation of returned data. So you need to clarify what exactly you are looking for.